# Smalltalk on-line open source code repositories

Tags: open-source, package, libraries, smalltalk, repository

I want to collect a list of open and accessible source code repositories of Smalltalk code. I know there is the main SqueakSource and other custom SqueakSource's around there and Monticello is the right tool to access these repositories, and VisualWorks seems to have a main "Store" to access repositories.

Which other Smalltalk code repositories can you list? What's the right tool to access in GNU Smalltalk, Smalltalk/X, VA, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/ has a few repositories. Some that I follow:

- https://github.com/pharogenesis/pharogenesis
- https://github.com/mcandre/quicksmash
- https://github.com/smarr/RoarVM
- https://github.com/timfel/gitocello

If you're using Gnu Smalltalk, I'd say that github might be your best bet, because of the many tools that work with git, rather than any failings of Monticello.

There are also people using gitorious:

- https://gitorious.org/pharo-build/
- https://gitorious.org/cogvm (a mirror of the official Cog source)

Lastly, there are quite a few repositories hosted by Google:

- http://code.google.com/p/pharo-newcompiler/
- http://code.google.com/p/xtreams/

and so on.

Answer (score 5):

Just for the sake of completeness a list of the public Monticello repositories:

- GemSource: http://seaside.gemstone.com/ss/
- Impara: http://source.impara.de/
- Lukas Renggli: http://source.lukas-renggli.ch/
- Squeak Development: http://source.squeakfoundation.org/
- Colin Putney: http://source.wiresong.ca/
- SqueakSourceJ: http://squeaksource.blueplane.jp/
- SqueakSource: http://www.squeaksource.com/

Answer (score 4):

VA Smalltalk uses ENVY and there is a http://vastgoodies.com/

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget just searching for code using http://www.google.com/codesearch and selecting "Smalltalk".